# Subsequent steps of SSIS transform are already green, is it complete?

Tags: ssis

I'm working on an SSIS transform that joins a table with roughly 100k rows to a table that has 300 million rows. I've been monitoring the transform, and just recently the final steps of the transform have lit up green, despite the MergeJoin and 300million record source table still being yellow. Since this is an inner join, it wouldn't surprise me if it found all of the matching rows, but is this guaranteed by the state of the colors in the diagram?

[image]

Comment: Is this data flow inside of a Loop Container?

Comment: Nope, this data flow is the only item in the control flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the colors are correct.

The left input (Frozen CustTrans) has run out of rows, and the Merge Join has detected that there are no more matches. It has already sent the End of Rowset marker along with it's final buffer, which is why the downstream components have turned green. The other components stay yellow because they are still processing data - each source component will continue until all rows have been read.